# How can I restrict class instances in PHP?

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, registry

I'm relatively new to PHP (and to programming in general). Keep that in mind.

Here's the basic scenario. I am building a web-based mini-university.

There are two key classes: **Lesson** and **LessonSeries**.

- **Lesson** has a Series property, which stores a singular LessonSeries *if that lesson belongs to a series. It may not.*
- **LessonSeries** has a Lessons property, which will hold an array of Lesson objects..

Both classes have an 'Id' property, which is an integer and will be unique to their class. My database ensures there will not be two Lessons or two LessonSeries with the same Id.

In numerous pages throughout my website, Lesson objects are iterated and (if they have a series), they will display the series they belong to, and sometimes use some of the other LessonSeries methods and properties.

**So here's the issue:** When a Lesson is pulled from the Db, it constructs a LessonSeries to correspond to it. But I don't want there to exist 20 instances of the same LessonSeries. Certain methods trigger a db query that only needs to be executed once per LessonSeries. This could lead to exponentially more db activity than necessary if there were 20 instances of essentially the same series.

I'm new to programming patterns, but here's what I *think* I need:

- I want a registry of unique LessonSeries.
- I want each unique LessonSeries to be shared by all lessons that
  belong to it.
- Ideally, I want this functionality to be within the LessonSeries class, without having to have a second manager class, if it's at all possible.
- Basically, what I want is that, whenever a LessonSeries is constructed, the registry will be checked first for the existence of an the id. If so, what is returned is a reference to the existing LessonSeries. If it DOESN'T exist in the registry, then it is created as usual.

With this said, I have no idea how to make this happen in PHP.

*Edit:*
It was pointed out in the comments that I need to demonstrate I've attempted to solve the problem for this to be a good question, of sorts, on SO. But that's exactly my problem.

I considered doing something like this:

```
class LessonSeries {

private static $registry;

public $Id;
public $SeriesName;
public $ImagePath;
public $Description;
private $index;
private $lessons;
private $lessonCount;

public function __construct($seriesName, $imagePath=null, $Id=null, $description = null) {
    if(isset(self::$registry[$id])){
        return self::$registry[$Id];
    }else{
        $this->SeriesName = $seriesName;
        $this->ImagePath = $imagePath;
        $this->Id = $Id;
        $this->Description = $description;
        self::$registry[$Id] = $this;
    }    
}
```

However, I don't think this is how php constructors work. I think I know how to do what I want in Python (using subclasses and such), but PHP doesn't have subclasses. And that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do.

1. Create a factory object. Move all creation/caching logic there.
2. Pass that factory to newly created lessons and series so that they could delegate creation to it.
3. In your page code, strat by creating a factory.
4. Try to avoid statics if you can. For instance, your code will be easier to unit test if it's real objects.

Here's a pseudo-code demonstrating it:

```
class LessonsFactory {
  private $lessons = [];
  private $series = [];

  public getLesson($id) {
    if (isset($this->lessons[$id])) {
        return $this->lessons[$id];
    }
    $lesson = $this->loadLesson($id);
    $this->lessons[$id] = $lesson;
    $this->getSeries($lesson[$id]);
  }

  private loadLesson($id) {
    $data = ... // load lesson from db
    return new Lesson($data, $this);
  }

  public getSeries($id) {
    if (isset($this->series[$id])) {
        return $this->series[$id];
    }
    $series = $this->loadSeries($id);
    $this->series[$id] = $series;
  }

  private loadSeries($id) {
    $data = ... // load series from db
    return new LessonSeries($data, $this);
  }
}


class Lesson {
  private $factory;

  public function __construct($data, LessonFactory $factory) {
     $this->factory = $factory;

     // + code to intialize object with $data
  }

  // this is how you get series from lessons
  public function getSeries() {
    return $this->factory->getSeries($this->seriesId);
  }
}

// somewhere in your page controller code
$factory = new LessonsFactory();
$lesson = $factory->getLesson($_GET['lessond_id']);
```